make office-js word addin appear by default
is there a way to make an office-js word addin appear in the home ribbon by default, without user interaction through going to My Add-ins via O365 Admin panel or group policy?

Yes. You configure the manifest to enable the add-in to open automatically on installation or automatically when a document opens. The main task in both cases is to set the taskpane ID to a special name.
<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
  <TaskpaneId>Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument</TaskpaneId>
  <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" />
</Action>

